# SQL Server Recursive Cartesian

Tags: sql, sql-server

Although this is my very first SO question, I've spent over a decade getting answers from this site and it's become my first stop for solving issues ... so I'd like to say thanks to everyone who makes SO such an awesome resource.

I've searched the SO (and the web in general) for help on this problem and haven't found any solutions/examples.  I might not be searching for the right term, so please feel free to just offer topics for me to research.

I need to generate all possible combinations (but not permutations) of items in a parent table such that the combinations of parents which have overlapping children are excluded.  I need all combinations up to the count of unique children (in this case there are 3, but it can vary).  Each parent will have a unique combination of children.  No two parents can have the same children.

**Some sample data to clarify my ask:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Parent', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Parent 
IF OBJECT_ID('Child', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Child 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (101, 'A') 
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (102, 'B')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (103, 'C')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (104, 'D')

CREATE TABLE dbo.Child
(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Child VALUES (1, 101, '1')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (2, 102, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (3, 103, '1')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (4, 103, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (5, 104, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (6, 104, '3')
```

**So, in summary, the data looks like:**

4 Parents (A, B, C, and D)

3 Children (1, 2, and 3)

Children are assigned as follows:

Parent A --> assigned children: 1

Parent B --> assigned children: 2

Parent C --> assigned children: 1 and 2

Parent D --> assigned children: 2 and 3

**My desired Result Set:**

```
A
B
C
D
A, B
A, D
```

**Excluded Combinations Rationale**

Rationale for "missing" results:
"B, A" and "D, A" should be excluded because they are the same combinations as "A, B" and "A, D".  I need unique combinations, not permutations.

"A, C", "B, C" and "B, D" are excluded because A and C have children in common ("A, C" share Child "1", "B, C" share child "2", and "B, D" share child "2").

"A, B, D" (and all other 3 Parent combinations) are excluded because they all have children in common (e.g. "A, B, D" is invalid as B and D share child "2")

I tried using CTE to accomplish this but I don't think it's the right answer since I don't really have a hierarchy.  I really need a Cartesianed result set (Parent to Parent) but I need the Cartesian to happen repeatedly (with the depth set by the count of unique children) and I need any Cartesian results that share children to be excluded.

I appreciate any assistance.  Please let me know if I can provide any additional information.

[SQL Server Version 14 running on Windows Server 2016]

Comment: I don't follow, how are `'A'` and `'B'` related to each other? Is your expected result set delimited, or do the first 4 row have `NULL` for the value of their second column?

Comment: I don't see any reason why this would be recursive as there is no way to go more than 1 deep. A parent has 1:many children... A child doesn't have children (at least that I can tell). Unless there is something I'm missing (perhaps the same thing Larnu is missing as well?)

Comment: And what about C/D ?

Comment: Larnu - the result set isn't necessarily delimited, I was just providing the combinations of parents which would work for the sample data I provided.

Comment: JNevill - I'm not sure it's recursive either except that I need all combinations and the combination depth is the count of unique children.  So, for example, if we had children 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 then we might have a combination "A, J, L, K, T, V" (assuming those parents didn't have a child in common) as well as many other "6 parent combinations).  I used "recursive" because Cartesian against itself feels "recursive" to me.  So I may be misusing the term.

Comment: Gordon Linoff - The C/D combination cannot exist because C and D share child "2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: a slightly faster approach (still using the iteration over parents) and also limiting the number of parents in the combination up to the number of distinct children (this check is not actually needed when ALL parents have at least one child). You could still improve the performance by creating and enforcing indexes and also pre-calculating and alphabetical ordinal/number/column in the Parent table and using that to find the next parent in order: eg. use a.LastMemberOrdinal < p.NameOrdinal instead of a.LastMember < p.Name)

```
;with 
a
as
(   
    select cast(Name as nvarchar(max)) as ConcatName, Name as LastMember, isnull(oa.childagg, '') as childagg , 1 as NoOfParentsInCombination, (select count(distinct Name) from Child) AS distinctChildren
    from Parent as p
    outer apply --children of parent, aggregated
    (
        select
        (
        select ',' + name 
        from Child as c
        where c.ParentId = p.Id
        for xml path('')
        ) as childagg
    ) as oa
    union all
    select a.ConcatName + ',' + p.Name, p.Name, a.childagg + isnull(oa.childagg, '') as childagg, a.NoOfParentsInCombination + 1 as NoParentsInCombination, a.distinctChildren
    from a
    join Parent as p on a.LastMember < p.Name --consider only parents p which come after the last parent/member added in the previous iterations
    outer apply --children of parent, aggregated
    (
        select
        (
        select ',' + name 
        from Child as c 
        where c.ParentId = p.Id
        for xml path('')
        ) as childagg
    ) as oa
    where a.NoOfParentsInCombination < a.distinctChildren --limit number of parents in combinations up to distinct children [this is not really needed(?) if all parents have at least one child...but it improves performance(!)]
    and not exists
    (
    select * 
    from child as pc
    where pc.ParentId = p.Id
    and a.childagg+',' like '%,'+pc.Name+',%' --the children of the p parent do not appear in the aggregated children of all previous iterations/parents
    )
)
select *
from a;
```

Starting from parents, recursion to form combinations of parent names (alphabetically ordered), get children and count occurrences of children for each combo (each child should appear once, i.e, deriving from one parent in the combination). Not performant..

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Parent', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Parent 
IF OBJECT_ID('Child', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.Child 

CREATE TABLE dbo.Parent
(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (101, 'A') 
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (102, 'B')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (103, 'C')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (104, 'D')
INSERT INTO Parent VALUES (105, 'E')

CREATE TABLE dbo.Child
(
  ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Child VALUES (1, 101, '1')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (2, 102, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (3, 103, '1')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (4, 103, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (5, 104, '2')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (6, 104, '3')
INSERT INTO Child VALUES (7, 105, '3');

with a
as
(   
    select cast(Name as nvarchar(max)) as ConcatName, 0 as lvl
    from Parent
    union all
    select a.ConcatName + ',' + p.Name, a.lvl + 1
    from a
    join Parent as p on a.ConcatName < p.Name
    where a.ConcatName+',' not like '%,'+ p.Name + ',%'
    and right(a.ConcatName, isnull(nullif(charindex(',', reverse(a.ConcatName)), 0)-1, 0)) < p.Name
),
b
as
(
select top (100) percent ConcatName, cc.Name AS ChildName, count(*) ChildOccur
from a
join Parent as pp on ',' + a.ConcatName +','  like '%,'+ pp.Name + ',%'
join child as cc on pp.Id = cc.ParentID
group by ConcatName, cc.Name
order by concatname
)
select ConcatName
from b
group by ConcatName
having count(*) = count(distinct ChildName)
and max(ChildOccur) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks lptr.  I struggle with CTE but the responses which don't use CTE don't seem to providing the depth (of the Cartesian) that I need. Your response does but I'm still struggling through it.  One question - how can I limit the depth (e.g. if I have 5 unique children I can only have up to five parents in a group).  I tried "OPTION (MAXRECURSION X)" but I get a "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion X has been exhausted before statement completion." regardless of the value I supply.

Comment: Please don't use this "sql abomination" (i.e my answer) because it is so bad performance-wise that could easily be the worst possible approach. If you think about it, there is no reason to form all combinations first, then join by manipulating strings and finally aggregate to find children that appear once.  A more simple approach is: when recursing add only parents which don't have common children with the parents already added in the previous iterations(it is that easy and also shows how bad the original answer is). I'll edit the answer later (in the meantime just have a go at it)

Comment: as for the depth, there is already a "value" you can work with...hint: use more parents and better to start "it" counting from 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
-- Just get the parents individually
select      
distinct    Name 
from        parent

-- Join parents to each other.  
-- Effectively a cross join to get all pair combinations.
-- Except you use the inequality to avoid repeats
union all   
select      l.Name + r.Name
from        Parent l
join        Parent r on l.Name < r.Name

-- For the pairs of parents, query the count for each child.
-- Then get the max count.
cross apply (select maxChildren = (
                select max(n) from (
                    select      c.Name, 
                                n = count(*) 
                    from        Parent p
                    left join   Child c on p.ID = c.ParentID
                    where       p.Name in (l.Name, r.Name)
                    group by    c.Name 
                ) x)
            ) mc

-- Filter out any pairs where the max count of children
-- exceeds 1.
where       mc.maxChildren <= 1
```

Comment: Thanks pwilcox. Like LukStores approach, this seems simpler to me since it doesn't use CTE but how could I extend it to address more than two groupings (e.g. ABC, etc.).  The number of groupings will be equal to the number of unique children.  It's entirely possible to have 10 parents each with unique children.  In such a case, I'd have 10 groupings (e.g. "A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, and J").

Answer (score 0):

If it's just to find the parent pairs that don't share a child.

Then you can self-join on the bigger ID.
And then filter those where for no child exists that has both parents.

**Sample data:**
*(using temporary tables for demonstration)*

> ```
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Parent', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
>   DROP TABLE #Parent;
>
> CREATE TABLE #Parent
> (
>   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>   Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO #Parent VALUES 
>   (101, 'A') 
> , (102, 'B')
> , (103, 'C')
> , (104, 'D')
> ;
>
>
> IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Child', 'U') IS NOT NULL 
>   DROP TABLE #Child;
>
> CREATE TABLE #Child
> (
>   ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
>   ParentID int NOT NULL,
>   Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
> );
>
> INSERT INTO #Child VALUES 
>   (1, 101, '1')
> , (2, 102, '2')
> , (3, 103, '1')
> , (4, 103, '2')
> , (5, 104, '2')
> , (6, 104, '3')
> ;
> ```

**Query:**

> ```
> SELECT p1.Name AS Name1,
>  CASE 
>  WHEN p1.ID != p2.ID THEN p2.Name
>  ELSE ''
>  END AS Name2
> FROM #Parent p1
> LEFT JOIN #Parent p2
>   ON p2.ID >= p1.ID
> WHERE NOT EXISTS
> (
>      SELECT 1
>      FROM #Child ch
>      WHERE ch.ParentID IN (p1.ID, p2.ID)
>      GROUP BY ch.Name
>      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ch.ParentID) > 1
> )
> ORDER BY IIF(p1.ID=p2.ID,0,1), p1.ID, p2.ID
> ```
>
> ```
> Name1 | Name2
> :---- | :----
> A     |      
> B     |      
> C     |      
> D     |      
> A     | B    
> A     | D
> ```

A more complicated query that also uses recursion :

> ```
> WITH RCTE_POSSIBLE_COMBOS AS
> (  -- possible combinations
>    SELECT 
>      ID AS BaseID
>    , Name AS BaseName
>    , 0 AS Lvl
>    , ID
>    , Name
>    , CAST(Name AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS Combo
>    FROM #Parent
>
>    UNION ALL
>
>    SELECT 
>      c.BaseID
>    , c.BaseName
>    , c.Lvl+1
>    , t.ID
>    , t.Name
>    , CAST(CONCAT(c.Combo,',',t.Name) AS VARCHAR(MAX))
>    FROM RCTE_POSSIBLE_COMBOS c
>    JOIN #Parent t ON t.Name > c.Name
> )
> , CTE_EXISTING_PAIRS AS
> (
>   SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(p1.Name,',',p2.Name) AS Pair
>   FROM #Parent p1
>   JOIN #Parent p2
>   ON p2.ID > p1.ID
>   WHERE EXISTS
>   (
>      SELECT 1
>      FROM #Child ch
>      WHERE ch.ParentID IN (p1.ID, p2.ID)
>      GROUP BY ch.Name
>      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ch.ParentID) > 1
>   )
> )
> SELECT p.Combo
> FROM RCTE_POSSIBLE_COMBOS p
> LEFT JOIN CTE_EXISTING_PAIRS e
>   ON p.Combo LIKE '%'+e.Pair+'%'
> WHERE e.Pair IS NULL
> ORDER BY LEN(p.Combo), p.Combo
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | Combo |
> | :---- |
> | A     |
> | B     |
> | C     |
> | D     |
> | A,B   |
> | A,D   |
> ```

A test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b7b95ae18e987085cf8bc47571121194)*

Comment: Thanks LukStorms.  This approach seems simpler to me since it doesn't use CTE but how could I extend it to address more than two groupings.  It's entirely possible my result data could have 3, 6, 12, or more "groupings" (e.g. Name1, Name2, Name3, ...).  Does meeting that requirement necessitate CTE?

Comment: If you don't know how many level deep it goes. Then yeah, a recursive CTE would be the way to through them.Btw, I had already put a query with a recursive in the dbfiddle. But I couldn't find how to filter the existing combinations, so I gave up on it. But maybe it can give you an idea.

Comment: @mmuse I gave it another try and added a second query.  But since one doesn't know how  many names can be in a combination it outputs a string.